# Xcode 9.1 Image not found: libBacktraceRecording.dylib

Tags: ios, c, xcode, macos, dylib

Since updating Xcode to 9.1 from 9.0, all of my projects compile and start, but now crash and output:

```
dyld: could not load inserted library '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib' because image not found
```

for all of my projects. Is anyone else experience this problem? Is there a simple solution to fixing it? I cleaned the build and deleted the derived data, but to no avail.

Comment: Reinstall Xcode from clean?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the issue by either

1. Disabling lib backtrace recording[image]
2. In terminal, check if libBacktraceRecording.dylib is missing or not.

`ls /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib|grep libBacktraceRecording`

If missing, 
`open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib` on your friends computer and copy `libBacktraceRecording.dylib` to your `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib`